# Run an JMeter script in non-gui to generate a new report with a random name without delete previous reports

Tags: performance, jenkins, testing, command-line, jmeter

This is my bat file:

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin
CALL rd /s /q C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\HTML
CALL Del "C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\log.csv"
jmeter.bat -n -t C:\NewPerformanceTask\EdidtedNewJmeterscript.jmx ^
-l C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\log.csv -e -o C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\HTML ^
-Jduration=%1 -Jusers=%2 -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true
```

As you can see here, I always delete the previous report and after finishing the run, another report is generated. How can I keep all reports and generate a report with a random name after each run?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the [time of the execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format) to your folder, for example  using script

```
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hour=0%time:~1,1%
...
-o C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\HTML\%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%hour%%time:~3,2%
```

Comment: and I need to delete this two lines from my bat file?                                                           CALL rd /s /q C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\HTML
CALL Del "C:\NewPerformanceTask\Raport\log.csv"

Comment: @VadimPasat you can use `-f` , see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

Answer (score 0):

You can add a current timestamp to your .jtl file name i.e. replace `log.csv` with something like `log-%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.csv`

[image]

If you need to overwrite the results with the newer ones it's easier just to provide [`-f` command-line option](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), it's available since [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/four-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answers. They helped me solve the problem